# How to add rfcomm and genericAttributeProfile device capabilities to Package.appxmanifest in Windows 8.1.

Tags: bluetooth, windows-store-apps, gatt, rfcomm, appxmanifest

I need to support multiple devices including both serial and BLE. When i add the following code to Package.appxmanifest file, i get an error

Unable to activate Windows Store app 'blah.blah_blah!App'. The activation request failed with error 'E_INVALIDARG'.

```
<m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="name:heartRate"/>
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>

<m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
   <m2:Device Id="any">
     <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reappeared your project’s error. If you just add Bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile or Bluetooth.rfcom, that is ok. So I think the error caused by citing repeatability and you can follow the below step to add Bluetooth and add all Bluetooth’s services. 
[image]

in the code Behind, you could add RfcommDeviceService by `var rfcommDeviceService = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService;`
 and add gattDeviceService by `var gattDeviceService = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattDeviceService;`.